# How to bring up two columns in SQL

Tags: sql

I am basically trying to retrieve two records from my database. It brings back one column `deleted` but if I have orders of less than 200 in another column I need to show those in the datagrid view too

I have this query so far....

```
select deleted, orders 
from DATABASENAME 
where deleted = 1 and orders = < 500
```

I keep getting a error of incorrect syntax :S

Comment: Less than or equal to like this: **<=**

Comment: You also know you are selecting less than 500 via your query (and orders <= 500), but per your instruction you say "orders less than 200"

Answer (score 2):

Your logic operator is incorrect :

```
select deleted, orders from DATABASENAME where deleted = 1 and orders <= 500
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to do as I don't think you are using the terms correctly.

```
select deleted, orders from DATABASENAME where deleted = 1 and orders = <500
```

1. Has a problems with the "= <" as have been pointed out.
2. DATABASENAME is possible misleading. That should be a table name, but maybe you have a table named DATABASENAME. That would be odd.
3. Your say "...I need to show those in the datagrid view too" which to me connotes logical OR rather than the AND.

So maybe you want

```
select deleted
     , orders 
  from [table] 
 where deleted = 1 
    or orders <=500
```

Answer (score 0):

Also as noted by others, DATABASENAME is misleading and should refer to your table name (even if fully-qualified i.e. schema.table, it's still a table name), and your logical operator is wrong (`<=` instead of `= <` as you have it)

If you're still having problems, what does this query produce?

```
    SELECT deleted, orders
        FROM DATABASENAME
        WHERE deleted = 1;
```

I would append a `LIMIT 1` to the end of that query if your table is huge. I've given the above to illustrate that if a query I'm writing doesn't give me the expected results, it's often helpful to isolate issues by removing clauses from it until I can see where the problem is coming from. For your case, do you actually have data where orders is less than or equal to 500?